# Парсинг Json

Tags: android, java, json

Посоветуйте библиотеку для парсинга JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пожалуйста: [org.json](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/org/json/package-summary.html). Примеры: [работа с JSON в Java](http://goloburdin.blogspot.com/2011/03/json-java.html).