# Распарсить строку используя регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, android, java

Всем добрый вечер, столкнулся со следующей проблемой! Необходимо распарсить следующую строку:

```
{“status”:”success”, “token”:”TOKEN”}
```

Необходимо создать две стринговые переменные в которых будут храниться значения `status` и `token`.

Пробую регуляркой, но что то не выходит. И может кто нибудь даст ссылочку на хорошую инфу по работе с регулярками?

Comment: Ясно сейчас начнутся умничанья типа зачем JSON парсить регуляркой и тому подобное. Я вообще не понимаю, почему когда человек не знает ответа на заданный вопрос начинает рассказывать о своих знаниях не касающихся данного вопроса. Неужели вы думаете, что мой Google работает хуже вашего? Попробуйте ответить на вопрос! Поймите еще, что указать автору, что это не просто строка можно и в комментариях, а не в ответе на поставленный вопрос!

Comment: [Ссылочка](https://www.google.ru/search?redir_esc=&client=ms-android-google&hl=ru-RU&safe=images&q=%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BB%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F&source=android-browser-suggest&qsubts=1378054565083&devloc=0) на хорошую инфу по работе с регулярками.

Comment: @vanyamelikov а вам совершенно по делу говорят про JSON, а потому ваш крик души несколько неуместен. Если вам хочется делать бесполезную работу, которую давным-давно сделали за вас (это я про самодельный парсинг) - ради бога. Но зачем удивляться тому, что другие люди в отличие от вас не хотят забивать гвозди микроскопом, а вместо этого советуют пользоваться молотком?

Answer (score 5):

это же json.
для него есть специальная библиотека.

[вот пример как использовать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

конечно, если хочется извращений, то можно и регулярками воспользоваться

UPD

[первая ссылка в гугле как парсить регулярками простой json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384454/split-json-objects-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: Я знаю, что это JSON, но суть вопроса как распарсить это регулярками?

Comment: обновил свой ответ

Answer (score 3):

Это похоже на JSON объект... Если это так, то может лучше [средствами парсинга JSON'ов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/137470/java-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-json)?

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще удобная тестилка регулярок. Часто пользуюсь. При наведении на текст, показывает результат выражения.
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/